# Dte.LaunchWizard not showing New Item dialog

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am trying to add a new item from an item template from a Visual Studio command. I cannot get Visual Studio to show the New Item dialog. This is in Visual Studio 2022.

Regardless of whether I use ItemOperations.AddNewItem or EnvDTE.LaunchWizard(Constants.vsWizardAddItem, ref parameters), the item is added correctly - but silently - with the default name.

This is my code to add the item using LaunchWizard (*item* is ProjectItem of the currently selected physical folder):

```
var template = ((Solution2)dte.Solution).GetProjectItemTemplate(templateName, "CSharp");

var prms = new object[]
{
    Constants.vsWizardAddItem,
    item.Name,
    item.ProjectItems,
    item.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value?.ToString(),
    "Bag",
    string.Empty,
    false
};

var cached = dte.SuppressUI;

dte.SuppressUI = false;

try
{
    dte.LaunchWizard(template, ref prms);
}
finally
{
    dte.SuppressUI = cached;
}
```

The last value of false in the parameter array should mean that the New Item dialog is displayed. But this does not happen, the item is added silently with the default name ("Bag"). I thought maybe the EnvDTE.SuppressUI property could be the reason but setting this to false changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

We can see from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.launchwizard?view=visualstudiosdk-2019&viewFallbackFrom=visualstudiosdk-2022):

> The first parameter is a GUID that uniquely identifies the launch
> context as distinct from Add Item or Add Project or a custom GUID.

Maybe [this page](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/main/docs/extensibility/internals/context-parameters.md) can give you some help about ContextParams.

From the documentation we can see that it doesn't apply to VS 2022 SDK. Maybe you can try it in VS 2019.
[image]

Comment: Even though the documentation does not mention VS2022 it would be very surprising if this was not supported.

My problem remains that regardless of the boolean value of the last Silent parameter to the wizard, the code runs without displaying the Add New Item dialog allowing the user to name the new item. Instead, the new item is silently created with the default name passed to the wizard.